# Integers of the form $m^k-n^k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

We know that an integer number is the difference of two squares if and only if it is not congruent to 2 mod 4. As a generalization, do we have a similar statement for  integers of the form $m^k-n^k$, where $k\geq 2$ is a fixed integer?

Comment: With $k>2$, such differences are getting increasingly rare (_have zero density_), so there is definitely no answer in terms of "_something mod something"_.