# Write a number as different differences of powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a positive integer $n$ that can be written as $a_i-b_i$ for $i=2,3,4,5$, where $a_i,b_i$ are positive perfect $i$th powers, and no two among $a_i$ or $b_i$ are the same?

This might be related to [the question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807876/integers-of-the-form-mk-nk) which asks when a number is a difference of two $k$th powers. For squares, we know this is the case iff a number is not $2\pmod 4$.

Comment: Can $a^i$, $b^i$ be negative (e.g. $(-1)^3$)?

Comment: No, they should be positive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. And there are infinite of them.

---

Since $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$, we can easily find $a_2,b_2$ by factoring the difference and solving a linear equation. So the real problem would be finding $g^5-h^5=e^4-f^4=c^3-d^3$.

Through brute-forcing $g^5-h^5=e^4-f^4$, we could find several candidates, first of which is
$$ 275^4 - 66^4 = 97^5 - 78^5 = 11^4 \cdot 19 \cdot 31 \cdot 661 \tag1 $$
(I think this is solvable without brute force but I don't bother to check :p )

---

We now try to solve $c^3 - d^3 = pq$. We factor the LHS into $(c-d)(c^2+cd+d^2)=pq$, then we have
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
c-d &= p\\
c^2 + cd + d^2 &= q
\end{aligned}\right. \implies c,d = \frac{\sqrt{3(4q-p^2)}\pm3p}{6}$$
In order for $c,d\in\mathbb Q$, we need $3(4q-p^2)$ to be a perfect square. Here we pick $p, q$ such that $pq\mid n$ for reasons explained in the next section. Using the factors in (1), we will use:
$$ 20^3 - 9^3 = 11 \cdot 661 \tag2 $$

---

OK so now we have got 3 equations,
\begin{align}
20^3 - 9^3 &= 11\cdot 661 \tag3 \\
275^4 - 66^4 &= (11\cdot 661) \cdot (11^3 \cdot 19\cdot 31) \tag4 \\
97^5 - 78^5 &= (11\cdot 661) \cdot (11^3 \cdot 19\cdot 31) \tag5
\end{align}
Now notice that we can multiply both sides of (4), (5) by $r^{20}$ for any $r$ without changing the "shape". This is why we pick $pq\mid n$ before. We choose $r = 19\cdot 31$ so that the factor becomes a perfect cube:
\begin{align}
(11^3 \cdot 19^{21}\cdot 31^{21})\cdot(20^3 - 9^3) &= (11\cdot 661) \cdot (11^3 \cdot 19^{21}\cdot 31^{21}) \tag6 \\
(275r^5)^4 - (66r^5)^4 &= (11\cdot 661) \cdot (11^3 \cdot 19^{21}\cdot 31^{21}) \tag7 \\
(97r^4)^5 - (78r^4)^5 &= (11\cdot 661) \cdot (11^3 \cdot 19^{21}\cdot 31^{21}) \tag8
\end{align}

---

Finally we just need to find $a^2 - b^2 = (11\cdot 661) \cdot (11^3 \cdot 19^{21}\cdot 31^{21})$, which is pretty trivial (just make sure you don't pick perfect square $a,b$ which coincide with the quartic solutions).

\begin{align}
& 143943941566433550753732821282296405837497469123172655460549556689 \\
&= 11^4 \cdot 19^{21} \cdot 31^{21} \cdot 661 \\
&= 6235538756477338734239125439443855^2 - 6223985832403904367008453242140156^2 \\
&= \left( 20 \cdot 11\cdot19^7\cdot31^7 \right)^3 - \left( 9 \cdot 11\cdot19^7\cdot31^7 \right)^3 \\
&= \left( 275 \cdot 19^5 \cdot 31^5 \right)^4 - \left( 66 \cdot 19^5 \cdot 31^5 \right)^4 \\
&= \left( 97 \cdot 19^4 \cdot 31^4 \right)^5 - \left( 78 \cdot 19^4 \cdot 31^4 \right)^5
\end{align}
You could check that all 8 numbers are also different. (Note that, now we have got this solution, every $nk^{60}$ for every $k$ will also be a solution, not to mention there are many other base solutions.)